# Python request for Google Drive

Tags: python, google-api, python-requests

I am trying to use python requests library to send a file to Google Drive api. The only thing I need it to send a multipart request according to google documentation
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#multipart
I need to send the meta data first and then the file. Here is what I tried so far

```
    def upload_csv(self, file, description):
      self.refresh()
      url = self.url+'?uploadType=multipart&' + urllib.urlencode({'key':self.api_key})

      headers = { 'Authorization':'Bearer {}'.format(self.access_token),
    #                    'content-type':'multipart/related',
    #                    'content-length':size
                }

      data =  {'title':file,'description':description }
      files = {'file':(file,open(file,'rb'),'text/csv')}
      response = requests.post( url, headers = headers, data = data, files = files )
```

but I get back an error: u'Bad content type.  Please use multipart.
Is there a way to send meta data and the file using requests

Comment: What version of `requests` is this? 2.x already produces a compatible request.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to arrange the order of data and file using requests to post multipart/form-data?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21091802), but that's for the *reverse* of what you want.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out a way to do it. The problem is Google wants the meta data and the file together.

```
    def upload_csv(self, file, description):
      self.refresh()
      url = self.url+'?uploadType=multipart&convert=true' +   urllib.urlencode({'key':self.api_key})

      headers = { 'Authorization':'Bearer {}'.format(self.access_token) }

      class DataDict(dict):
          def read(self):
              return str( self )

      data = ('metadata',DataDict(title = file,description = description),'application/json; charset=UTF-8')
      file = (file,open(file,'rb'),'text/csv')
      files = {'data':data, 'file':file }
      response = requests.post( url, headers = headers, files = files )
      return respone
```

Comment: You are indirectly producing JSON; just use the `json` module instead to produce the metadata entry.